# ANSI/NIST-ITL vs XML which one to choose?

Tags: xml, biometrics

I am working on biometrics projects. The output of bio kits is typically done in XML or ANSI/NIST-ITL. Does anyone know why certain government institutions would prefer one over another?

Can you share a thread on advantages/disadvantages of ANSI/NIST-ITL over XML?

Comment: Not familiar with NIST format, is it a binary file format ? maybe older system that use those data only read binary NIST files  and cannot be updated to read XML (text) files ?

Comment: hi. Actually its a mix, some gov products now shift to NIST, others stick with XML. I dont think it has to do with technology age.